# Best way to load subpages? PHP or JS?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm wondering whether it's better to load subpages using PHP or JS. As yet, I've been using JS  (jQuery, stricly speaking) in order to provide some fancy loading animations but this technique has one serious drawback - it can't change the URL address so the user doesn't have a use of browser's back button, nor can't share the URL of the exact subpage. Besides, I'm not sure if search engine bots recognize JS-based subpages. Or maybe I'm wrong and it is all posible with JS?

If not, then what is the "right way" to organize subpages in PHP? Am I obliged to use frameworks even for small websites? So far I've been using only PHP's `include()` method for this purpose.

Comment: Why would people use *both* if one of them was clearly superior in every circumstance? This is like asking if plastic is better than steel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes JavaScript can update the browser's URL, but it only works in HTML5 compliant browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

The `replaceState` function changes the URL in the browser (no back button); the `pushState` function pushes the new URL to the browser so the back button can be used.

Example:

```
history.pushState({}, 'Title', 'foo.html');
```

This may help you with your problem.

Comment: nice, `pushState` changes the URL, but the back button is still useless - it doesn't load the previous page, only changes the URL back

Comment: @OverdrivenFall you can, read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Example carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Good way (there is no best way): Use a server side language (like PHP) for templating. Put Javascript/jQuery on top of that - so you have the best of two worlds, fancy animations for javascript enabled users and a still working page as a fallback. There are also jQuery history plugins that enable bookmarking/history featured in the browser after an ajax load.

You do not need a framework for small sites. However if you want to load content depending on user input you need a way to validate request variables and a framework might help with that.

As for SEO in the javascript approach, search engines do not usually execute javascript. However they will propably index the files you pull in via javascript (I guess you store content in text files or html files which will be indexed).

Answer (score 0):

Loading subpages with JS is meaningful for dynamic content.
For static pages, I would recommend using PHP.

You really do not need to use frameworks, but be sure not to include a file using uncontrolled GET/POST variables (for security reasons).

Answer (score 0):

The method I used was to have sub-forms written in PHP and loaded via an AJAX call done with JQuery.

In reality, the AJAX called a PHP responder and passed a value with the form name. The form was retrieved [with `include(...)`] and the resultant HTML captured using output buffering.

The folder layout I used was:

```
lib
|
+-subforms
| |
| +-admin
| | +-aform1.php
| | +-aform2.php
| | + :
| | + aformn.php
| |
| +-client
| | +-cform1.php
| | +-cform2.php
| | + :
| | + cformn.php
|
+-supportFunctions.php
```

where  `lib` refers to the include path for the app

The AJAX call passed the value selected in a drop-down box which correlates to the form name to retrieve.